# IPad - Is there a way to conditionally keep the native keyboard closed?

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm working on an Ionic 4 / Cordova app and trying to implement a custom numpad style keyboard for certain input fields. I want to prevent the native keyboard from opening when focussing on those specific inputs. I tried using the `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard` package and call `.hide()` on the keyboard direct after the focus event, but you can see the native keyboard jump up a bit. Also calling `.hide()` breaks focus because that's how the plugin hides the keyboard: 
`[self.webView endEditing:YES];`

Is there a way to tell the keyboard to stop responding to the focus events?

One solution I'm trying to avoid is building a 'mock input field' from the ground up, I'm looking for a way to disable the keyboard itself.

Comment: Would changing the `<input>` `type`, `pattern`, or `inputmode` resolve the issue? https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/

Comment: This was a helpful comment. After reading the article I started playing around with the inputmode and found that you can set it to 'none'. which will prevent the keyboard from opening all together!.